# Trouble overriding the Django Admin template files

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

I have seen this question answered but I can't get it to work on my site. I have installed a site using Django 1.8 as I wanted to use the [django-admin-bootstrapped](https://github.com/django-admin-bootstrapped/django-admin-bootstrapped) plugin. I am also using the [template provided by Heroku](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-django-template).

What I would like to do is override at the very least the base_site.html to change the site title and page title. However, I have tried several locations for this file including the following:

```
PROJECT ROOT
  |--templates
     |--admin
        |--base_site.html


PROJECT ROOT
  |--templates
     |--admin
        |--<appname>
           |--base_site.html

PROJECT ROOT
  |--<appname>
     |--templates
        |--admin
           |--base_site.html

PROJECT ROOT
  |--<appname>
     |--templates
        |--admin
          |--<appname>
             |--base_site.html
```

None of which work. I have the following in my settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
        'debug': DEBUG,
    },
},
]
```

I am just wondering if I am doing something fundamentally wrong or if I just haven't found the magic location for the templates folder (or order of folders etc).

On a related note, is there anyway of debugging where the templates are being pulled from or is it just guesswork based on where they are supposed to be coming from?

Answer (score 0):

> Not every template in contrib/admin/templates/admin may be overridden per **app or per model**. The following can:
>
> - app_index.html
> - change_form.html
> - change_list.html
> - delete_confirmation.html
> - object_history.html

[enter link description here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#templates-which-may-be-overridden-per-app-or-model)

Override `change_list.html` to change the site title and page title

Comment: perhaps my question is misleading - I don't want to extend the template but rather replace the default.